# c# WPF XAML RelativeSource reference to ComboBox.Resources item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am working on a reusable template for a WPF `ComboBox`. I am able to dynamically change the font color, background, and border by using these references in the template:

```
Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=Foreground}"
BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=BorderBrush}"
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=Background}"
```

These were easy since I had properties I could reference.

```
<ComboBox Margin="90,62,0,0" Height="26" Width="302"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Focusable="False" IsReadOnly="True" MaxDropDownHeight="202" 
          Foreground="White" Background="SteelBlue" BorderBrush="White"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemFlatStyle}">
```

What I would like to do is reference the following in a similar manner:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxHighlightBrush" Color="RoyalBlue" />
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Is it possible to reference a resource inside the control? I really want to be able to reuse this template on another `ComboBox` using difference colors.

Comment: Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxHighlightBrush}" works on anything inside your combobox, is this what you meant?

Comment: @Milan Nope, I have a Style in my Application Resources.

Comment: Foreground="{DynamicResource ComboBoxHighlightBrush}" works if your brush is defined in app.xaml resources. i now get that you actually want to access a resource, which is not inside your application resources, but inside a combobox which is inside your application resources. but is this not a sign that you actually want this brush to be globaly accessible?

Comment: @Milan No...I do not want the brush globally accessed. I am trying to create a template style. I want to use resources inside a control to define elements of the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fairly certain the answer was no, but then again ControlTemplates are bound to the targeted type's properties at run time right? So then I thought as long as "Resources" is an accessible property of the ComboBox object at run time there should be a way. I verified by using [snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) that "Resources" was indeed a readable property at run time:

[image]

Since Resources is just a dictionary, I then tried to set the background of the combobox dropdown to a resource defined exactly the same way as you did by adding these attributes to the "DropdownBorder" element in the default ComboBox control template:

```
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Resources[ComboBoxHighlightBrush]}"
```

This will likely give you a compile time error saying that "Resources" is not accessible - but it's not an error that'll truly prevent you from building the solution and running it. At run time you'll see that it indeed works!

**Despite it working**, I'm not sure this is the best way to go about making your template reusable. Other than the annoying compile-time error, a consumer of the template will have to know about this magic string in order to add a correctly keyed brush to the resource dictionary.

I would consider the following:

1. A common way to lightly add to the behavior of an existing UI control is to used attached properties. You can bind to attached properties in ControlTemplates. This way you have something typed and not relying on a magic string.
2. Create a full on custom control. In my UI project I often have a need to have default text or a docked item at the top of my combobox drop down, so I created a custom control which has additional dependency properties that allows these features, but also allows me to modify colors that WPF's ComboBox doesn't let me out of the box.

*Edit* Based on your code, I think my interpretation of your question using ControlTemplates is correct.. if not the above won't make sense. If so, I also want to mention you should probably do bindings like

```
Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
```

instead of

```
Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=Foreground}"
```

If anything just for easier reading. It's also a faster binding iirc.

Comment: Just tested and I actually had no compiler errors. For me this works very well as I am the only person using this template. Thanks!

Comment: Huh, you're right, the initial "Resources is not accessible" disappeared shortly after I built it. I guess I jumped to a conclusion since I'm used to WPF's random not-really-an-error-errors. :)